# in how many ways 10 adults 60 children (20 boys 40 girls) can be placed in a row,

Tags: combinatorics

In how many ways $10$ adults and $60$ children ($20$ boys $40$ girls) can be placed in a row, such that between $2$ adjacent adults are exactly $6$ kids? The answer is $7*10!*60!$. Why do we multiply by 7? Can someone explain the solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are $10$ adults, then there are $9$ gaps between the adults to place $9 \times 6=54$ children.  The remaining $6$ children are placed outside the adults, and this can be done in $7$ ways (all on the left, 6 on the left and 1 on the right, and so on.)